# how to do select_related from multiple table

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-queryset, django-select-related

I have 3 models connected in this way:

```
class book(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    publisher= models.ForeignKey(Publisher, related_name='publisher')
class reader(models.Model):
    publisher= models.ForeignKey(Publisher)
class publisher(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField()
```

and i'm trying to get all the reader of specific book.
I tried to do: `Reader.objects.select_related(publisher__id='some_id')`
ang got err: `Unable to get repr for <class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>`
I cant change this model, there is way I can get this information with that models?
thanks.

Comment: why a `reader` has only the field `published`, a reader is supposed to read a book, right? where's the link?

Comment: There is something strange with your modeling, you link a reader to a *publisher*? People do not read publishers, they read books.

Comment: Furthermore the `related_name`, should probably be `'books'`, since related name is the name of the *opposite* direction: from `publisher` to `book`. I would really advice to first clean up your modelng, since essentially all business logic depends on the modeling.

Comment: Didn't you get any errors when you run the server apart from using "select_related"? I'm quiet sure the order of classes defines whether you can use another model as foreignkey. For example, you shouldn't be able to use publisher as foreign key in reader.

Comment: @almostabeginner: in fact he should be able. But the modeling is simply "*strange*". Unless the reader in this modeling is some professional proof reader that is hired by a publisher, it is strange that a reader does not have a key to a book.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem From my limited experience I always received errors when incorrectly ordering the classes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795930/does-order-of-declaration-matter-in-models-py-django-python

Comment: @almostabeginner: yes, if you pass a *reference*. But django allows to pass a string. So `'publisher'` instead of `publisher`. But regardless of that, the question is still unclear, and the OP has not added the essential details to help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use filter instead of select_related like so:

```
publishers = Publisher.objects.filter(book_id=<your_book_id>)

Reader.objects.filter(publisher__in=publishers)
```