# Python class forward declaration

Tags: python, forward-declaration

I'm trying to do following:

```
# Define a class named Type
class Type():
    def __init__(self, id, symbol):
        self.id = id
        self.symbol = symbol
    def is_free(self):
        return self.id = LAND.id

# Define variables of this class
LAND = Type(-1, '.')
```

I wonder if there is forward declaration of class in Python?

**EDIT:**

I have seen the post [Is it possible to forward-declare a function in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590608/is-it-possible-to-forward-declare-a-function-in-python), but I don't think it's the same issue. Because the question is about forward declaration of `function`, while I'm asking about `class`.

I also read this post [Does Python have class prototypes (or forward declarations)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524714/does-python-have-class-prototypes-or-forward-declarations), but it was asking about refer to a class in another class, while I'm asking about refer to variables of its own type within the class. I don't see my solution in this post, or can somebody who thinks it's duplicate explain a little bit?

Comment: @wim Please see my edit, I don't see this as a duplicate of [Does Python have class prototypes (or forward declarations)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524714/does-python-have-class-prototypes-or-forward-declarations)  Can you please help me remove the duplicate mark?

Comment: @wim Never mind, I have asked a new question.