# Use global variables defined by one class within the class

Tags: python

I'm trying to use global variables `LAND` which is an object of class `Type` within the class `Type`.

The following code gives me an error: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` because `LAND` is not defined:

```
# Define a class named Type
class Type():
    def __init__(self, id, symbol):
        self.id = id
        self.symbol = symbol
    def is_free(self):
        return self.id = LAND.id

# Define variables of this class
LAND = Type(-1, '.')
```

I can't just move `LAND` before the definition of `Type`, because that will also give me the error `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` because `Type` is not defined.

Can somebody tell me if it is possible? Or is there any alternative way to do this?

---

I have asked a question with a bad title [Python class forward declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49972457/python-class-forward-declaration), it was marked as duplicate with two questions, but as I explained in my original post, I don't think my question is the same as those two:

I have seen the post [Is it possible to forward-declare a function in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590608/is-it-possible-to-forward-declare-a-function-in-python), but I don't think it's the same issue. Because the question is about forward declaration of `function`, while I'm asking about `class`.

I also read this post [Does Python have class prototypes (or forward declarations)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524714/does-python-have-class-prototypes-or-forward-declarations), but it was asking about refer to a class in another class, while I'm asking about refer to variables of its own type within the class. I don't see my solution in this post, or can somebody who thinks it's duplicate explain a little bit?

Comment: If `LAND.id` is always -1, can't `is_free()` just check for that exact value?

Comment: @JohnGordon It can, but that will make code difficult to read. Consider `LAND` as a const variable.

Comment: @MartinZhai which version of python you are executing code? Actually in python2.7 code executed correctly.

Comment: `self.id = LAND.id` -> `self.id == LAND.id`?

Comment: Please show the full error. With stack trace. Something is missing here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Following code gives me error, `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` because `LAND` is not defined

No, you get a `SyntaxError` because an assignment `a = b` (in your specific case
 `self.id = LAND.id`) is not an expression, wich means that it does not produce a value which you would be able to `return`.

Your code works just fine when you change the `=` to a `==`, which is what I assume you want. Alternatively (I'm a bit unsure what is supposed to happen in your code), you could write two lines:

```
self.id = LAND.id
return self.id
```

Anyway, the problem here is not that `LAND` is not defined when `is_free` is created. That's not a problem, because nobody is calling `is_free` yet. The problem is that you probably thought (because you seem to come from a C background ) that an assignment with `=` produces a value, which is not the case in Python.