# How can two python classes declare references each other and itself?

Tags: python, mypy, recursive-datastructures

This is a very basic question that is actually two questions in one. The hopefully very simple answer that exposes my Python greenness is probably the same for both questions.

The following code has two problems:

- Class A `a:A=A()` creates a `NameError` because class A does not know that class A exists until its declaration is complete.
- Class A `b:B=B()` creates a `NameError` because class A does not know that class B exists until class B has been declared.

```py
    #! /usr/bin/python3.10
    
    class A:
       a:A=A()
       b:B=B()
    
    class B:
       a:A=A()
       b:B=B()
```

I am having type error and want to use mypy. If I create the variables outside of the class declarations as attributes or otherwise hide the desired types, then mypy will not see the type declarations and cannot parse my program for type errors.

Why would I want this, you might ask? Recursive data structures have infinitive applications, but...

- A situation where class A references itself is a simple link list. A link list eliminates the need to track indexes while allowing simple insert, delete, and next iterations at the cost of slow indexing which the application may not ever need.
- A situation where class A references class B which references class A is a simple container where class B (the container) contains a set of instances of class A (the items) which are aware of the containers they are in.

Can Python do these very basic things in a manner where mypy can be satisfied with the type declarations?

I am beginning of think that the 'python way' is for every function to type-check every parameter. The more I consider it, the more logical it is for an interpreted language to make such a requirement, but I would still like to keep my code as organized and declarative as possible.

Comment: The *class* that represents a linked list does not need to reference itself. Only an *instance* of the class needs to reference another instance.

Comment: You can't create an instance of a class in the same class body, the class doesn't exist yet. If you want to type annotate an attribute with the class that does not yet exist you can use `from __future__ import annotations`

Comment: You are defining class attributes, not instance attributes (though an annotated *name* in a `class` statement can by used to type-hint an instance attribute).

Comment: [Relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524714/does-python-have-class-prototypes-or-forward-declarations) fwiw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Answer edited following discussion in the comments.]

If you want a recursive class definition with an `__init__` method, then a proper implementation will depend on your goals, but [PirateNinjas's answer using `Optional`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69449943/5445670) is probably what you want. However, if you really need static class members, you can initialize them after declaring both classes:

```py
class A:
    a: 'A'
    b: 'B'

class B:
    a: 'A'
    b: 'B'

A.a = A()
A.b = B()
B.a = A()
B.b = B()
```

Answer (score 2):

I think part of your problem doesn't have a solution. Your declaration:

```
class A:
   a:A=A()
   b:B=B()
```

implies that A().a is another instance of A, which in turn references another A, and so on. This isn't necessarily a problem, but have it be part of the object creation or instantiation would automatically require an infinite number of the objects! Perhaps you could do something like:

```
from typing import Optional


class A:
    a: Optional["A"]
    def __init__(self, other: Optional["A"] = None):
        self.a = other
```

This would allow you to have a base case (self.a is None) and other cases where self.a is another instance of A.

Note the above also uses "A" to define the type. This gets you around the type-hinting issue, though I don't know how it plays with mypy! You could apply this so that your solution looks like:

```
from typing import Optional


class A:
    a: Optional["A"]
    b: Optional["B"]

class B:
    a: Optional["A"]
    b: Optional["B"]
```

Comment: Just a small thing: Given that the `a` (and `b`) could be `None`, all the type-hints should be `Optional["A"]` (and `Optional["B"]`)

Comment: that's a good point, thanks. Added it to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this answer comes very late, but probably it could be useful.

As you mention, the problem is that the class is not known until its definition ends. I had the same issue when PyCharm tried to lint a class definition with a method called "compare". The method was supposed to receive a parameter of the same class.
My easy to implement solution was to (pre)declare the class before the real declaration. In your case, that would look like:

```
class A:
    pass
class B:
    pass

class A:
    a:A=A()
    b:B=B()

class B:
    a:A=A()
    b:B=B()
```