# Can I somehow reference a Python class that is declared later than the class from which I need to reference without changing their order?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

I have these two Python classes(Pydantic schemas which represent SQLAlchemy models):

```
class Role(RoleBase):
    id: int
    users: list[User] = []

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True

class User(UserBase):
    id: int
    date_created: datetime.datetime
    profile_image: Optional[str] = None

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

I've tried to do it with ForwardRef:

```
User = ForwardRef('User')
...
users: list[User] = []
```

or to wrap it with quotes:

```
users: List['User'] = []
```

but I get `TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class`.

Is there some way to implement this **without changing classes' declaration order**?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524714/does-python-have-class-prototypes-or-forward-declarations) could help you, however, I'm not sure, so I didn't cast a vote to close

Comment: Did you call `User.update_forward_refs`?

Comment: @LeopardShark Yes, it doesn't work too

Comment: @Cid well, I didn't find, what I need. I guess I just have to reorder them

Comment: Sorry, it's not `User.update_forward_refs()` it's `Role.update_forward_refs()` that you need.

Comment: @LeopardShark YES, it works exactly as I need! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `pydantic.ForwardRef`, you need to call `update_forward_refs` on classes that have forward references to update them. So add

```py
Role.update_forward_refs()
```

after `User` is defined.

This will all be unnecessary if [PEP 649](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0649/) is accepted.